# Mock logging handler in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following logger setup:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('foo.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

How do I stop the logger from actually writing an entry to disk while unit testing? I am currently checking that `logger.error` is called as follows:

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.logger')
def test_error_is_logged(self, mock_logger):
    mymodule.func() # this causes an error to be logged
    self.assertTrue(mock_logger.error.called)
```

The above test works correctly, however the log file `foo.log` is created on disk which I want to avoid. All I want to know is if `logger.error` is called, while mocking the file creation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your case is, that the empty file 'foo.log' is already created in the moment the line

```
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('foo.log')
```

is executed.  You can avoid this by adding the `delay` argument:

```
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('foo.log', delay=True)
```

which will delay the creation of the file until some content is written to it.

Comment: lifesaver... I can't believe how long it took me to find this. Furthermore, I set it so that the loglevel would not write in my test with `logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)`